# Numeric Array as Default Answer for Input Dialog

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create an input dialog box in MATLAB, with the default answers filled in based on numbers that I call from an earlier transformation matrix. The problem is that no matter *what* I do, I cannot convert the numbers to a string, which means I cannot call them as a `defaultans` property. Basic conversions such as `num2str` don't work because the data can be negative. `char` also does not seem to work.

```
earlierData = [ 1 -1.2 3 5 -0.2 4];
prompt = {'Enter x translation:', 'Enter y translation:', 'Enter z translation:', 'Enter x rotation:', 'Enter y rotation:', 'Enter z rotation:'};
name = 'Enter the values for the desired rotation matrix.';
num_lines = 1;
defaultans = [ox, oy, oz, oxrot, oyrot, ozrot];
nTransform = inputdlg(prompt, name, num_lines, defaultans);

newTranslate = [str2double(nTransform{1}) str2double(nTransform{2}) str2double(nTransform{3})];
nxrot = str2double(nTransform{4});
nyrot = str2double(nTransform{5});
nzrot = str2double(nTransform{6});

% make new transformation matrix
rot = makehgtform('translate', newTranslate, 'xrotate', nxrot,...
    'yrotate', nyrot, 'zrotate', nzrot);
```

Comment: `num2str` works just fine on negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

`num2str` works just fine on negative numbers. You need to ensure that the default value for `inputdlg` is a *cell array of strings* rather than just a plain string. As such, you just need to put the output of `num2str` inside of a cell array:

```
default = [1.1 2.2 3.3];
nTransform = inputdlg('Prompt', 'Name', 1, {num2str(default)});
```

Now to load in the entered values:

```
numericValues = str2double(strsplit(nTransform{1}));
newTranslate = numericValues(1:3);
nxrot = numericValues(4);
nyrot = numericValues(5);
nzrot = numericValues(6);
```

Comment: Don't need `cellfun` with `str2double` it works fine on cell arrays.